# Are there methods to make an Iron Door open through right clicking while holding a specific item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know if one can open an iron door via right clicking, perhaps with a specific item in one's hand?

**Edit:** Since 1.8, there is a "lock" command. Does this command work with buttons? Or is it only for chests?

Comment: No, it just isn't how iron doors work. You can however use pressure plates or tripwires to open them automatically.

Comment: Yeah yeah, I know but I asked this for a map, it would help me a lot if we can do that ^^

Comment: You may want to add that edit of yours into a separate question entirely. Questions should focus only on one issue at a time.

Comment: In a map, if you have the time, you could go through and place (via setblock or fill) the piston extension block which disappears when right clicked. Then run a command to check if it vanishes and replace the door with an open one for a few seconds, then spawn the piston extension back in and reset the door.

Answer (score 1):

From [MinecraftInfo](http://www.minecraftinfo.com/irondoor.htm):

> **Clicking on an Iron Door does not change its open/closed state.** The only way to open or close an iron door is via Levers, Stone
>   Buttons, Wood Pressure Plate, Stone Pressure Plates and Redstone
>   Torchs.

Comment: I know that, but my question is can we open it via special item given by commands blocks

Comment: @Fyrens I don't quite think that's how it works.

Comment: @Texenox actually it can be done sorta. It would require scoreboard and a lag free server (you don't open the door. You destroy and replace with nbt data so lag could leave a vulnerable moment. And you can even play the open sound. )

Comment: @ydobonebi, can you make that an answer?

Comment: I don't know the commands well enough.  I've seen it done. So not really worth an answer if I can show the method. If I have time after midterms I'll put it together and show.